# How to set a native object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

ok so im creating a jquery plugin that will allow me to use the new html5 Audio interface and im trying to create an option that is an object that you will be able to set the various listeners but i dont seem to be able to set those options to the listener property of the Audio object.

ok so ive got as far as the plugin being able to run the functions of the element now i need to be able to set the tons of listeners that the element has

Answer (score 0):

To get the native DOM element wrapped by a jQuery object, write `$(...)[0]`.

If this does not answer your question, please provide more detail.

Comment: ok so ive got as far as the plugin being able to run the functions of the element now i need to be able to set the tons of listeners that the element has